# Bootstrap validator custom validation doesn't work after clear cache

Tags: jquery, forms, bootstrapvalidator

I am using [this](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/).
SO the main problem is that if I clear cache `CTRl+F5` my custom validation function doesn't work anymore, if I hit F5 after clear cache all works good.

Initially I thought that was something about the order of loading of the libraries in html, because I've had `defer` to jquery and custom validation in another source file which was requested after jquery in html. But I've removed the defer because I got `$ - unknown function` error anyway and still the code doesn't work after clear cache

Other problems(because of the lack of documentation) are:

- usage of custom errors
- the fact that if I use custom error with default `data-error` the custom one is not showed

I'm gonna make a preview below

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("form").validator(
        {
            custom :{
                result: function($el) {
                    if ($el.val().trim() != 10) {
                        return "Worng answer from validator"
                    }
                }
            },
            errors:{
                //this never works
                'result':"Wrong answer from errors"
            }
        }
    );
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.js"></script>



<form data-toggle="validator" role="form"  id="formValidator" class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputCaptcha" class="control-label">5 + 5 = this has error from html</label>
    <input type="text" data-result="Wrong answer from html"  data-result-error="Wrong from html" class="form-control" id="inputCaptcha" placeholder="Answer here" required>
    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
   </div>
      <!--  ******************************** -->
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputCaptcha" class="control-label">5 + 5 = this has error from validator</label>
    <input type="text" data-result  data-result-error class="form-control" id="inputCaptcha" placeholder="Answer here" required>
    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Try to view it a a full page and test with clear cache

Comment: unfortunately here seems to work with or without cache

Comment: so the problem is you site not the implementation

Comment: @madalinivascu - maybe, also I've put the code in HTML directly, below jquery request and same

Comment: @madalinivascu - now it's not working here too, I've use a newer jQuery version(the one from my site), this was the problem

Comment: did you find a solution for this? with newer versions of jquery.